# Targeting Chromecast with CSS Media Queries

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

What CSS3 Media Queries can we use to target Chromecast in the graphics view?

It doesn't seem to respond at all to something like:

```
@media tv and (device-width: 1280px){...}
```

The only query I have been able to get to work was:

```
@media(min-width: 1265px){...}
```

Which seems bonkers to me because the overscan is 32px anyway.

What are the best queries to use?

So far the best layout I have found is:

```
@media(min-width: 1265px) {
    body {
        position: absolute;
        top: 18px;
        right: 32px;
        bottom: 18px;
        left: 32px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
}
```

Which allows for the 18px * 32px overscan and an apparent additional 5px margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neil, I am not aware of a clean way to do this through Media Query at this point but you can potentially use the user agent fingerprint to discover that you are on the chromecast device; for example if strings "CrKey" and "TV" are in the user agent, then you are running on the chromecast.

Comment: Thanks Ali, it would be great if the CC Dev team could implement a consistent min-width media selector.  Is there a public bug tracker we can submit this sort of thing to?

Comment: I did create an internal feature request to that effect.

Comment: As of 12 Feb 2014, the Chromecast userAgent no longer contains "TV". Mine is "Mozilla/5.0 (CrKey armv7l 1.4.15250) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.0 Safari/537.36".